# Is there a limit to the number of SQL Server CE 4.0 databases I can use within a WebMatrix web project?

Tags: sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I'm currently working on a WebMatrix web project (mainly because this may eventually be sold as a standalone web product to companies without external access to the Internet).  I'm aware of the current SQL Server CE restrictions of 4GB and 256 connections.  I'm considering slicing off several of the data-intense tables (logging, catalog resource lookup, etc) into different databases to avoid the 4GB limit.  I will not be querying across databases.  Will I run into a problem if I use multiple CE databases on the project?

Thanks! --Kevin

Comment: One of the biggest problems I would say is that it will be a maintainability nightmare. Trying to avoid writing tonnes of ugly data-tier code will be tricky. Do you *really* need the database for logging, or some other functions? What about a single DB and abstract other layers out to disk/IO/Other?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use a "real" database server ? With such volumes of data, it really is recommended.

Comment: Well, no matter how big your disk - at some point, you'll run out of disk space! :-)

Comment: I don't see maintainability as a serious problem.  I'm just going to use separate data connection strings for the different logical database units.  That way they can be configured to point to different data sources (for the smaller CE databases) or to a single data source (for our in-house use).  A "real" database server will be used in-house, but I'm still building to use CE instances in case we end up selling the solution as a package to smaller companies that may not have a full IT staff to configure and maintain a larger database.

Answer (score 1):

No - there is no limit to the number of SQL CE databases you can add to a Web Pages site. If you are able to cleanly separate the various data-related tasks into different databases, you shouldn't have any technical problems either.

Comment: THANKS!  That's what I was hoping for, but couldn't find any info.